# Whole dataset shows up, although a subset has been selected and newly defined

Tags: r

I a dataframe which I have subsetted using normal indexing. Code below.

```
dframe <- dframe[1:10, c(-3,-7:-10)]
```

But when I write dframe$Symbol I get the output.

```
BABA ORCL LFC  TSM  ACT  ABBV MA   ABEV KMI  UPS 
3285 Levels: A AA AA^B AAC AAN AAP AAT AAV AB ABB ABBV ABC ABEV ABG ABM ABR ABR^A ABR^B ABR^C ABRN ABT ABX ACC ACCO ACE ACG ACH ACI ACM ACN ACP ACRE ACT ACT^A ACW ADC ADM ADPT ADS ADT ADX AEB AEC AED AEE AEG AEH AEK AEL AEM AEO AEP AER AES AES^C AET AF AF^C ... ZX
```

I'm wondering what is happening here. Does the dframe dataframe only contain 10 rows or still all rows, but only outputs 10 rows?

Thanks

Comment: The `Symbol` is factor class.  You need to use `droplevels` or call `factor` again to drop the unused levels.  try `dframe <- droplevels(dframe[1:10, c(-3, -7:-10)])`

Comment: Thanks! Is there any significant performance drawbacks in not dropping the factors?

Comment: If you are subsetting 10 rows from 1e6 dataset with 1e5 levels for a columns, without dropping the levels, it may still have to hold that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way factors work. When you subset a factor, it preserves all levels, even those that are no longer represented in the subset. For example:

```
f1 <- factor(letters);
f1;
##  [1] a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
## Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
f2 <- f1[1:10];
f2;
##  [1] a b c d e f g h i j
## Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

---

To answer your question, it's actually slightly tricky to append all missing levels to a factor. You have to combine the existing factor data with all missing indexes (here I'm referring to the integer indexes that the factor class internally uses to map the actual factor data to its levels vector, which is stored as an attribute on the factor object), and then rebuild a factor (using the original levels) from that combined data. Below I demonstrate this, now randomizing the subset taken from `f1` to demonstrate that order does not matter:

```
set.seed(1); f3 <- sample(f1,10);
f3;
##  [1] g j n u e s w m l b
## Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
factor(c(f3,setdiff(1:nlevels(f3),as.integer(f3))),labels=levels(f3));
##  [1] g j n u e s w m l b a c d f h i k o p q r t v x y z
## Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Comment: Interesting! May I ask then, how do I reverse the process, meaning how can I make the data object contain all the values again, including the values not longer represented but who still show up.

Comment: Are you saying you want to append to the factor data all of its levels that are no longer represented? So for my example above, you want to append to `f2` levels `k` through `z`?